# How to use 7zip

Tags: powershell, zip

i have 1 big script which does all the job of restoring back up and deleteing the existing one. However before doing that i call my backup script from the main script which backs up the existing site before deleting it and restoring it to the previous state.  but when my backup script runs (which i am  calling from main script) at the same time the files gets deleted, i want to put a wait so that the backup finishes first than the current files gets deleted and than previous backup is restored and files are pasted on their respective folders.

This is my main script which is

$content = get-childitem 'C:\Backups\my_site'
   $sortedContent = $content |  Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending

write-host "This is the list of all the backups for my_site :"

$count = 1
   foreach ($item in $sortedContent)
   {

```
Write-Host ("{0}: {1}" -f $count, $item.Name)
$count++ 
}



# 2.Take input from user
$itemNumber = Read-Host "Please select which backup you want to restore"
$confirmation = Read-Host "Are you Sure You Want To Proceed:"
# 2.Take input from user

if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {

# 3. BACKUP script
```

./backup_mysite.ps1
    # 3. BACKUP

```
# 4. DELETE CONTENTS OF my_site


get-childitem "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my_site\" -recurse | % {

remove-item $_.FullName -recurse -force

}

}


# 4. DELETE CONTENTS OF APP

# 5. COPY CONTENTS OF ZIP INTO APP DIRECTORY
$itemNumber = $itemNumber -1
if($sortedContent[$itemNumber].PSIsContainer -eq $true)
{ 
$src = $sortedContent[$itemNumber].FullName + "\"


$WebzipPath = $src + "my_site.zip"


$Date = Get-Date
$folder_date = $Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm")
$tempPath = 'C:\_Temp\Restore\my_site_restore_' + $folder_date
if (!(Test-Path -path $tempPath)) 
{
    New-Item $tempPath -type directory
}   


./Library/unzip.ps1 $WebzipPath $tempPath



$tempPathWeb = $tempPath + "/my_site/*" 

Copy-Item  -Path $tempPat -Destination 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my_site\' -Recurse -
force
```

The zip script which i am using is this

```
$path = $args[0]
$files = $input

if (-not $path.EndsWith('.zip')) {$path += '.zip'} 

if (-not (test-path $path)) { 
set-content $path ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18)) 
} 

$ZipFile = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace($path) 
$files | foreach {$zipfile.CopyHere($_.fullname)}
```

Some body suggested me that i cannot use this zip script because its async, That person suggested me to use 7zip to do all the zipping, but i dont know how to that , this is my backup script which than calls the above zip script for all the zipping.

```
$Service_folder_name = 'C:\Services\'
$Pics_folder_name = 'C:\Pics\'


$Date = Get-Date

$folder_date = $Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm")

$backup_folder_name = 'c:\_Backups\my_site\' + $folder_date

if (!(Test-Path -path $backup_folder_name)) {

New-Item $backup_folder_name -type directory
}

if ((Test-Path -path $Pics_folder_name)) {
gi $pics_folder_name | .\Library\out-zip.ps1 $backup_folder_name\pics.zip $_
}

if ((Test-Path -path $Service_folder_name)) {
gi $Service_folder_name | .\Library\out-zip.ps1 $backup_folder_name\Services.zip $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function awhile ago for working with 7zip, this one uses 7za.exe which is a standalone.  It should give you a good idea of how to use it synchronously.

```
Function out-7zip
{
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Will add files to a zip package

.DESCRIPTION
Uses the 7za.exe standalone component to add files to an archive, if the archive specified in the path doesn't exist it will create a new archive automatically.

.EXAMPLE
ls c:\logs -recurse | Where {(!($_.PSiscontainer))} | out-7zip -path c:\logs.zip

-----------------

Adds all files from the c:\logs directory to the c:\logs.zip archive

.EXAMPLE
get-item c:\logs | out-7zip -path c:\newzipfile.zip

----------------

Takes the c:\logs directory and adds it, and it's contents to a new archive called newzipfile.zip

.NOTES
Writen by Jason Morgan
Last Modified 8/5/2013


#>
[cmdletbinding()]
Param
(
    # Accepts a file system object that will get added to the zip file
    [Parameter( 
    ValueFromPipeline=$True, 
    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True,
    HelpMessage='This Parameter requires a filesystem object as input')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Default')]
    [PSObject]$inputobject,
    # Set the path to the new or existing zip archive
    [Parameter(
    Mandatory=$true,
    HelpMessage='Path to the zip file, can be a new zip file or an existing archive')]
    [ValidateScript({$_.endswith('.zip')})]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Default')]
    [string]$path,
    #Path to 7za.exe file
    [Parameter(
    Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateScript({$_.endswith('7za.exe')})]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Default')]
    [String]$ZipApp = 'C:\ISDps\Configs\7za.exe'
)
Process
{
    $inputobject | foreach {
        Try
            {
                [Array]$arguments = "a", "-tzip", $path, $_.fullname
                Start-Process -FilePath $ZipApp -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait | Out-Null
            }
        Catch
            {
                Write-Error "Unable to add $($_.fullname) to $path"
            }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: sorry a little confused, can you please specify in my case how can i use your script]

Comment: Well you will need to load the function, either by dot sourcing a script or just putting it into you script as is.  You need to either change the default value for $zipapp to your path or override it using the parameter.  And then you can just pipe the files you're zipping to it like you do with out-zip.ps1.

Comment: If you load the function you can check out the help to see some examples of how to use it.

Comment: i have a last question, how to add 7zip path ( # Set the path to the new or existing zip archive) and ( #Path to 7za.exe file) can you lease clarify  this  i am not sure about the syntax can you please modify your script with a dummy path thanks

Comment: You set those values using the parameters `-ZipApp` and `-Path`. Once you've loaded the function it works just like a cmdlet.  You can view help, check out examples, and feed in arguments using parameters.

Comment: `ls .\mydir | out-7zip -path c:\newzip.zip -zipapp c:\tools\7za.exe`